# Using Google Admin SDK Reports API with Google App Maker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I'm trying to make an app on App Maker that reports on all deleted calendar events, and who the organiser was when they were deleted. I've managed to get all events using the calendar API by simply calling "CalendarApp" in the serverside script:

```
var calendars = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
```

However this API doesn't have the functionality I need. (Checking for deleted events)

I need to use the reports API to get all of the deleted calendar events, however 
how i would normally call it in apps script -

```
var response = AdminReports.Activities.list(userKey, applicationName, optionalArgs);
```

Doesn't work on the App Maker script. The console returns this error:

> AdminReports is not defined

I've also taken a look on this answer below, however the solution doesnt seem to work for me.

[Access Admin SDK with Google App Maker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47442099/access-admin-sdk-with-google-app-maker)

So the bottom line is, can I easily access the Reports API on App Maker? And if so, what would be the easiest way to do it?

EDIT: when trying to enable the reports API, it switches straight to the directory API. These are not the same thing. Is this a bug?

Comment: Well, did you enable the service? If you didn't, then of course the associated client library - defined only if you have enabled the corresponding service - will not be defined in your code.

Comment: Looks like you have not enabled AdminReports Advanced services in Appmaker. Refer [this](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/settings). Refer 'Advanced Google Services' section which provides the answer on how to adding one.

Comment: Okay, there seems to be a bug with the service. Whenever I turn on the reports API, it defaults to the admin Directory API, which isn't the same thing anymore.